# Display an image using OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a button image and I have a project with OpenGL and I have managed to create a window now I want to add an image of a button onto that window.

Is there an easy way to display a .bmp or .png?

Comment: Displaying an image in OpenGL boils down to 1. generate and initialize texture object, 2. load image into texture, 3. draw a quad with the texture applied.

Comment: Just to add to the above. Images in OpenGL are referred to as textures. There are plenty of tutorials on textures.

Comment: Also OpenGL does deals only with raw images in the form of RGBA textures, you will need some other library to decode image formats.

Comment: Check out [stb_image](https://github.com/nothings/stb) to load images.

Answer (score 0):

> "so is there a easy way to display"

According to the following introduction:
http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/graphics-draw.php

The people at SFML make it seem as though it is not easy to do that with OpenGL. So, if you want it to be easy, use SFML.

> "but I dont understand how to use SFML"

The tutorials are very simple to learn, and if a beginner like me can figure it out, then so can you.

http://www.sfml-dev.org/learn.php